# How to use the database sqlite3 provided by Python, outside of Python

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am doing some C++ programming on Ubuntu Linux.
The Python interpreter is already installed on my development machine by default; as you know, sqlite3 database is normally part of default Python installation.
Despite this, by typing "whereis sqlite3" on console, sqlite3 does not seem to be installed.

> myusername@domain:~$ whereis sqlite
>   sqlite:

Is there any way to use sqlite installation provided by Python interpreter, "outside" Python?
Just to avoid duplicates on hd.

Thanks

IT

Comment: What Python have is a Python-specific SQLite3 *module*, not the complete installation.

Comment: How about searching for C++ bindings for that database on the internet?

Comment: Are you talking about `sqlite` or `sqlite2` or `sqlite3`?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: what you are saying is interesting.
Could you explain me what you means?

Comment: @CL. Python 2.7 includes sqlite3.

Comment: Your title and tags say SQLite 2 but your question says SQLite 3. Which is it?

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: In fact, Python 2.7 includes the sqlite3 module.
I have corrected the title and tags of the post, thanks for letting me notice. :-)